# latex alignment based on basis vectors

Tags: equations, align, matrices

I'd like to align 2 equations based on the position of the basis vectors like this

[image]

I'm using this code:

```
$\begin{matrix}
    \bm{A}=a_1&\bm{\sigma_1}-a_2&\bm{\sigma_2}+\ldots + a_3&\bm{\sigma_{2n-1}}-a_4&\bm{\sigma_{2n}}
 \\ 
    \bm{B}=b_1&\bm{\sigma_1}-b_2&\bm{\sigma_2}+\ldots + b_3&\bm{\sigma_{2n-1}}-b_4&\bm{\sigma_{2n}}
\end{matrix}$
```

but there is so much space between the basis vectors \sigma_i and the coefficients. How can I can get a more compact equation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `array`. I declare eleven columns; first a right aligned one, then pairs of `c` and `r`; the `c` column is for the operation or relation signs, with added empty atoms to get the spacing right.

I use `r` columns, so the smaller width of `b` is masked by the spacing around the operation sign.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm,array}

\begin{document}

\[
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{array}{ r *{5}{ >{{}}c<{{}} r } }
\bm{A} &=&
  a_1\bm{\sigma}_1 &-&
  a_2\bm{\sigma}_2 &+&
  \cdots &+&
  a_{2n-1}\bm{\sigma}_{2n-1} &-&
  a_{2n}\bm{\sigma}_{2n}
\\[1ex]
\bm{B} &=&
  b_1\bm{\sigma}_1 &-&
  b_2\bm{\sigma}_2 &+&
  \cdots &+&
  b_{2n-1}\bm{\sigma}_{2n-1} &-&
  b_{2n}\bm{\sigma}_{2n}
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Note that `\bm{\sigma_2}` is wrong as the index is a number.

[image]

Comment: thank you.. it looks perfect!!

Answer (score 3):

Remember n alignment points requires 2n–1 `&`, and place them judiciously:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{5}
    \bm{A}&= a_1 & & \bm{\sigma_1}-a_2& & \bm{\sigma_2} +\dots + a_3& &\bm{\sigma_{2n-1}}-a_4& &\bm{\sigma_{2n}}
 \\
    \bm{B}&= b_1 & &\bm{\sigma_1} -b_2& & \bm{\sigma_2} +\dots + b_3 && \bm{\sigma_{2n-1}}-b_4 & &\bm{\sigma_{2n}}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With `alignat`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{5}
    \bm{A}&= a_1\bm{\sigma_1} &-a_2\bm{\sigma_2} &+\ldots &+ a_3\bm{\sigma_{2n-1}} &-a_4\bm{\sigma_{2n}}
 \\ 
    \bm{B}&= b_1\bm{\sigma_1} &-b_2\bm{\sigma_2} &+\ldots &+ b_3\bm{\sigma_{2n-1}} &-b_4\bm{\sigma_{2n}}
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You need `{} + a_3` and `{} + b_3`.

Comment: Thank your for your answer. It does the job. However, the array solution provide a more tailored solution to my needs because of the alignment of all term.